# Common cyphers where the plaintext is the same length as the cyphertext

Tags: xor, substitution-cipher

What are the common cyphers where the cyphertext is always the same length as the plaintext?

I can think of XOR cyphers, and letter-substitution cyphers, what others are there?

Answer (score 3):

Any cipher or cipher mode that implements [Format Preserving Encryption (FPE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) - by definition.

NIST has created a US standard document called [NIST Special Publication 800-38G: Recommendation for Block Cipher Modes of Operation: Methods for Format-Preserving Encryption](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/specialpublications/nist.sp.800-38g.pdf). This document lists two *modes of operation* abbreviated as FF1 and FF3. These are format-preserving, Feistel-based encryption modes. FF1 was previously known as FFX[Radix] and FF2 as BPS.

---

Stream ciphers or stream cipher modes of operation have the same property, but they have the problem that they require a nonce or IV, which typically has to be send with the ciphertext *unless* the state is otherwise synchronized between the party doing the encryption / decryption.

ECB and CBC mode have the same property, but the plaintext needs to be a certain number of full blocks and padding should *not* be applied. ECB is insecure and CBC also requires an IV to be used.

Commonly [disk encryption routines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption) have the same property as well, but they may restrict the input to a specific sized chunks. [ESSIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#Encrypted_salt-sector_initialization_vector_(ESSIV)) for instance uses a hash over the sector number and key to create an IV, sidestepping the issue that CBC requires an unpredictable IV.

So for symmetric ciphers / cipher modes this is a common property except that they often require an IV and sometimes padding. If the ciphertext also needs to authenticated then an additional authentication tag may be required as well.

---

Asymmetric ciphers commonly have to expand the ciphertext compared with the plaintext to be considered secure. RSA - for instance - could be used to have a ciphertext that is the same size as the plaintext, but the message space would have to be identical to the (randomly generated) modulus, and encrypting the values 0 and 1 would be completely insecure (because the modular exponentiation would not alter the plaintext message).